# How do you update your profile picture using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm experimenting on Microsoft Graph API to update the profile picture.

Although there is a documentation about it (See Link Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript), I can't seem to understand it.

I tried sending a random data to see if something would work, however I can only get the GET Method to work but somehow trying to make the PUT Method work returns an error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken",
        "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-04-15T07:10:11",
            "request-id": "********-****-****-****-************",
            "client-request-id": "********-****-****-****-************"
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the two concerns are:

1. How to use the PUT Method for updating the profile picture using Microsoft Graph API
2. Why am I receiving the error as if I'm not allowed to update?

   - Is it because I'm doing the PUT Method incorrectly?
   - Is it because I need some sort of subscription to use the API?

Comment: Put your access token https://jwt.ms and see if the permission User.ReadWrite Or User.ReadWrite.All are present or not.

Comment: Where and how are you testing the API?